# Phonegap/Cordova Barcodescanner fullscreen again on latest ios 13

Tags: ios, cordova, ios13

With the release of ios 13, the cordova barcodescanner plugin is no longer fullscreen but has a gap at the top.  This is because the default modal presentation style has changed in iOS 13.

How do you fix this breaking change?

Answer (score 0):

In the cordova-plugin-barcodescanner > CDVBarcodeScanner.mm file; set the ModalPresentationStyle of the viewController to Fullscreen in the openDialog method.

```
(void)openDialog {

    [self.viewController setModalPresentationStyle:UIModalPresentationFullScreen];

    [self.parentViewController
        presentViewController:self.viewController 
        animated: NO completion:nil];
}
```

Comment: In my case, it is not working to change it to fullscreen mode with https://github.com/phonegap/phonegap-plugin-barcodescanner